# Problem with Bootstrap 5 and Background Image in the Server Environment

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a problem that I can't solve on my own, so I am asking help.
In my web pages, all pictures are working fine in the server environment. Below is an example:

a. In Bootstrap 5 web pages, all images are entered like this, and everything works fine:
html [image: ...]

b. I want to start using background images. I tested this on my home laptop, and everything worked fine.
I can manage background images directly with HTML like this:
html 
OR with CSS like this:
css background-image: url('backimage.jpg');
Of course, I have other settings as well, and everything works fine.

c. BUT in the server environment, I can't enter a background image via url; I have to use the "img src" method.
I have tested many different options. Any ideas on how to solve this?

I have tested many different options, I tried to find instructions etc.

Comment: Can you share some code? It's probably a path issue. Don't you have error messages in your browser console?